# Show that $K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/m =K$ when $m$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory

If $K$ is an algebraic-closed field.  Show that $K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/m =K$ when $m$ is maximal.

---

We know that $K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/m$ is a field that contains $K$ because $m$ is maximal.

How can I show that $K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/m =K$ ?

Comment: Since $K$ is algebraically closed, the maximal ideals have a very specific form. Then see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677028/proving-kx-1-x-n-j-cong-k-iff-j-x-1-a-1-x-n-a-n-wher?rq=1 and also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008160/maximal-ideals-of-kx-1-x-n-and-points-in-kn?rq=1

Comment: @morrowmh without using Nullstellensatz. We need this to show that $m$ has this form.   I would like to prove that  If an algebraically closed field k is a subfield of a field L, and there is a
ring homomorphism from $k[X1,...,Xn]$ onto L (that is the identity on k),
then k = L.  without module theory.

Comment: This is the Zariski Lemma. Wikipedia has a page on it.

Comment: This also follows from Noether normalization.